# TSyringe and TypeORM importing Database dependencies BEFORE other dependencies

Tags: typescript, singleton, domain-driven-design, typeorm, tsyringe

I'm facing one problem, in which I have lots of Repositories(which they are TS Classes that implements one interfaces, they are **typeorm** repositories class) and I use TSyringe to handle all my dependencies in my API

Here is an example of one repository

```js
import { getRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import SafeUsd from '@modules/currencies/infra/typeorm/entities/SafeUsd';
import ICreateSafeUsdDTO from '@modules/currencies/dtos/ICreateSafeUsdDTO';
import ISafeUsdRepository from '@modules/currencies/repositories/ISafeUsdRepository';
import { classToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import IUpdateSafeUsdDTO from '@modules/currencies/dtos/IUpdateSafeUsdDTO';

export default class SafeUsdRepository implements ISafeUsdRepository {
  private ormRepository: Repository<SafeUsd>;

  constructor() {
    this.ormRepository = getRepository(SafeUsd);
  }

  async create(data: ICreateSafeUsdDTO): Promise<SafeUsd> {
    const safeUsd = this.ormRepository.create(data);

    await this.ormRepository.save(safeUsd);

    return classToClass(safeUsd);
  }

  async update({
    safeUsd,
    value,
    acceptable_variance,
    margin,
  }: IUpdateSafeUsdDTO): Promise<SafeUsd> {
    if (margin !== undefined) {
      safeUsd.margin = margin;
    }

    if (value !== undefined) {
      safeUsd.value = value;
    }

    if (acceptable_variance !== undefined) {
      safeUsd.acceptable_variance = acceptable_variance;
    }

    await this.ormRepository.save(safeUsd);

    return classToClass(safeUsd);
  }

  async findOne(): Promise<SafeUsd | undefined> {
    const safeUsd = await this.ormRepository.findOne();

    return classToClass(safeUsd);
  }
}
```

After that, I register all my repositories in one file, inside **"shared/container/repositories/index.ts"**

```js
import { container } from 'tsyringe';

import ICurrenciesRepository from '@modules/currencies/repositories/ICurrenciesRepository';
import CurrenciesRepository from '@modules/currencies/infra/typeorm/repositories/CurrenciesRepository';

import ICurrenciesUrlRepository from '@modules/currencies/repositories/ICurrenciesUrlRepository';
import CurrenciesUrlRepository from '@modules/currencies/infra/typeorm/repositories/CurrenciesUrlRepository';
import ISafeUsdRepository from '@modules/currencies/repositories/ISafeUsdRepository';
import SafeUsdRepository from '@modules/currencies/infra/typeorm/repositories/SafeUsdRepository';

container.registerSingleton<ICurrenciesRepository>(
  'CurrenciesRepository',
  CurrenciesRepository,
);

container.registerSingleton<ICurrenciesUrlRepository>(
  'CurrenciesUrlRepository',
  CurrenciesUrlRepository,
);

container.registerSingleton<ISafeUsdRepository>(
  'SafeUsdRepository',
  SafeUsdRepository,
);
```

In my app I also have some providers(which are basically implementations of third-partner APIs, such as AWS, GoogleFirebase, and so on...)

What I want to do is to inject some of my Repositories inside my providers, then I want to register their instances resolved by the TSyringe container.

The problem start when I try to do what I've just wrote above. When registering both my Repositories and Providers with the TSyring container, I do:

```js
import './repositories';
import './providers';
```

Which are both a lot of TS files that does the TSyringe container.registerSingleton, .resolve or .registerInstance methods.

I always get this error:

```sh
Error: Cannot inject the dependency at position #2 of "BitfinexBrokerProvider" constructor.
Reason:No repository for "Currency" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
```

This error, means that my Repositories haven't been up yet, so when TSyringe tries to inject them at my Providers, they heven't stablished connection with the database yet, so I get this error. If I don't inject those repositories inside my providers, everything works.

Any ideas on how to solve that? What I would like to do would be something like:

1. First resolve and register ALL repositories singletons, so they will connect with the DB.
2. Only after that, register all providers.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that? I hope I've made myself clear through my problem, Ask me if you guys have any doubt, I will edit the post trying to be more clear.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I've tried to add all TSyringe .registerSingleton() || .registerInstance() || .resolve(), inside one "setTimeout(() => {}, 3000)" and it worked! As I said in my problem, I just needed to wait a little so the DB connection is stablished on my repositories, before injecting on the providers.

**here you can see what I did**

```js
import { container } from 'tsyringe';

import BitfinexBrokerProvider from './implementations/BitfinexBrokerProvider';
import BrokerHandlerProvider from './implementations/BrokerHandlerProvider';
import FlowBTCBrokerProvider from './implementations/FlowBTCBrokerProvider';
import BitfinexChannelHandler from './implementations/websocket/bitfinex/ChannelHandler';

import IBrokerHandlerProvider from './models/IBrokerHandlerProvider';
import IBrokerProvider from './models/IBrokerProvider';
import IChannelHandler from './models/IChannelHandler';

setTimeout(() => {
  container.registerSingleton<IBrokerProvider>(
    'FlowBTCBrokerProvider',
    FlowBTCBrokerProvider,
  );

  container.registerSingleton<IChannelHandler>(
    'BitfinexChannelHandler',
    BitfinexChannelHandler,
  );

  const bitfinexBrokerProvider = container.resolve(BitfinexBrokerProvider);

  container.registerInstance<IBrokerProvider>(
    'BitfinexBrokerProvider',
    bitfinexBrokerProvider,
  );

  const brokerHandlerProvider = container.resolve(BrokerHandlerProvider);

  container.registerInstance<IBrokerHandlerProvider>(
    'BrokerProvider',
    brokerHandlerProvider,
  );
}, 3000);
```

Although it worked, I found this solution very unpleasant and not elegant. Is there a better way to achieve a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "delay" helper func inside of TSyringe. More details [here](http://%3C!--%20ngRepeat:%20message%20in%20messages%20%7C%20filter:%20%7Btype:%20%7Bid:%20type.id%7D%7D%20:%20true%20%7C%20filterCards:filterMessage:this%20%7C%20orderBy:%20sortMessagesFunc%20%7C%20limitTo:%20lazyLoadLimit%20--%3E)

Example:

```
@injectable()
export class Foo {
  constructor(@inject(delay(() => Bar)) public bar: Bar) {}
}

@injectable()
export class Bar {
  constructor(@inject(delay(() => Foo)) public foo: Foo) {}
}

// construction of foo is possible
const foo = container.resolve(Foo);

// property bar will hold a proxy that looks and acts as a real Bar instance.
foo.bar instanceof Bar; // true
```